# nodejs-Manully installing Packages behind corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to run nodejs behind a corporate proxy.Since it is behind proxy currently I am unable to install through npm.

I downloaded and placed the files for express js inside the project and try to run by var moduleName = require("express.js"). But it is throwing error .

Please help on how ton install express js manually in node.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to install express or other npm packages behind proxy (if you have a proxy server), you can setup proxy from npm config
using this:

`npm config set proxy http://proxy_host:port`

Comment: Unfortunatly after doing that also my proxy is blocking downloads

Comment: in that constrained environment, (if you have permission), you can set mirror server which has internet connection, and you will refer to that server as npm registry